# Runtime error 1004. Need to fetch value from another sheet in same Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function

```
Sub UpdateFormula()

    Dim CurrStr As String
    Dim EndRow As Long
    On Error GoTo 0

    EndRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    BaseStr = UCase(Range("A2").Value)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For iter = 4332 To EndRow
        CurrStr = UCase(Range("A" & iter).Value)
        result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CurrStr, Sheets("CustAR").Range("A2:A2499"), 1, False)

        '=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, CustAR!$A$2:$A2499, 1, FALSE)),"NotFound",VLOOKUP(A2, CustAR!$A$2:$A2499, 1, FALSE))

    Next iter

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

What's wrong in above code? I get error on the line where result is set.
Error is:

> Runtime error 1004 : Application or object defined error

What I am trying to do is to look for value in `CustAR` sheet. The Excel file has two worksheets including `CustAR` sheet.

The line next to "result" is the formula that works in Excel.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I modified the code as below and it worked.
I removed WorkSheetFunction and also handled the result value.

```
Sub UpdateFormula()

Dim CurrStr As String
Dim EndRow As Long
On Error GoTo 0

EndRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
BaseStr = UCase(Range("A2").Value)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For iter = 4332 To EndRow
```

On Error Resume Next

```
    result = Application.VLookup(CLng(CurrStr), shAR.Range("A2:A2499"), 1, False) '.WorksheetFunction

    If result = "Error 2042" Then
        result = "NotFound"
    Else
        result = result
    End If

    Cells(iter, 2).Value = result
    On Error GoTo 0
    '=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, CustAR!$A$2:$A2499, 1, FALSE)),"NotFound",VLOOKUP(A2, CustAR!$A$2:$A2499, 1, FALSE))

Next iter

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have either not dimensioned what `result` is.

OR

You have but as some sort of object, thus the line needs to be:

```
Set result = Application...
```

Answer (score 0):

VLOOKUP is searching for a string but it seems you have not provided one to be found - all numbers perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised you get that error message with your code, as I would have thought it would return:

[image: Error Message]

.  However, an equivalent for your worksheet formula might look as follows:

```
result = Application.VLookup(CurrStr, Sheets("CustAR").Range("A2:A2499"), 1, False)
If IsError(result) Then result = "NotFound"
```

Using VLookup as a property of the Application object, rather than as a property of the Worksheetfunction object, results in `result` *containing* an error code (in this case error 2042) instead of causing a VBA run-time error. An alternative would be to test for the VBA runtime error in your original code.